# Joomla 3.5 sub controllers/classes

Tags: php, joomla

I'm having problems with joomla 3.5 not finding a task in a subcontroller. I'm running J!Dump, and can see that it's running the subcontroller's contructor, but `/administrator/index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=subctrl.trask` returns `task [trask] not found` I tried using `$this->registerTask('trask', 'trask')` in the contructor, but it didn't help ... any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

> /administrator/components/com_mycomponent/controllers/subctrl.php

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die ;
class MycomponentControllerSubctrl extends JControllerAdmin
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->registerTask('trask', 'trask');
        dumpMessage('running controller');
        dump($this, 'Ctrler');
    }

    public function trask()
    {
        dumpMessage('running Ctrl Trask');
        return true;
    }
}
```

I get the following callstack:

```
#   Function    Location
1   JApplicationCms->execute()  /Users/evanion/Projects/php/joomla/administrator/index.php:51
2   JApplicationAdministrator->doExecute()  /Users/evanion/Projects/php/joomla/libraries/cms/application/cms.php:257
3   JApplicationAdministrator->dispatch()   /Users/evanion/Projects/php/joomla/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php:152
4   JComponentHelper::renderComponent() /Users/evanion/Projects/php/joomla/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php:98
5   JComponentHelper::executeComponent()    /Users/evanion/Projects/php/joomla/libraries/cms/component/helper.php:380
6   require_once()  /Users/evanion/Projects/php/joomla/libraries/cms/component/helper.php:405
7   JControllerLegacy->execute()    /Users/evanion/Projects/php/joomla/administrator/components/com_mycomponent/mycomponent.php:17
```

Here is the admin sections `mycomponent.php` file referenced in the callstack (some lines of comments removed for clarity):

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// Get an instance of the controller prefixed by HelloWorld
$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('Mycomponent');

// Perform the Request task
$controller->execute(JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('task'));

// Redirect if set by the controller
$controller->redirect();
```

The controllers directory is specified in the xml meta data for the admin folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can extend from `JControllerAdmin` for your purpose. You should extend from `JControllerForm` or  `JControllerLegacy`.